# Check if user input is = a defined string

Tags: c#, authentication

I am making a login terminal and I have a login string, so I want to check the if the user prints the name of the string correctly, do the following, Here is the code:

```
Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
Console.WriteLine("---LOGIN TERMINAL---");
Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("/Log In");
Console.WriteLine("/Create New User");
Console.WriteLine("/Delete User");

userInput = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
if(userInput = LogIn)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank You! I actually forgot because i didnt code for a long time, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

[`=` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) is an assignment operator. You need to use [`==` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) which is equality operator.

```
if(userInput == LogIn)
{

}
```

If this `LogIn` is not a variable, but a `string`, you need to use it with double quotes like;

```
if(userInput == "LogIn")
{

}
```

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Yes, there are also some extensions to warn you that you are not doing an equality check but assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
Console.WriteLine("---LOGIN TERMINAL---");
Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("/Log In");
Console.WriteLine("/Create New User");
Console.WriteLine("/Delete User");

var userInput = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
if(userInput == "Log In") // input check here
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter User Name");
    var userName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter User Password:");
    var password = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("User Name: {0}, Password: {1}", userName, password);
}
```